# How to separate or identify header/footer/carousell & other parts of any website?

Tags: php, html, web, programming-languages

I want to separate out header/footer/sidebar/carousel of homepage of any of the website.

Example if I enter google.com or alibaba.com or flipkart.com

I can retrieve that homepage via PHP CURL. (some of them are encoded which we can't)

But question is how to identify that? Each platform is using different programming language.

Is they any API available free/paid in market? Is it possible?

Here what I have tried

```
  $url = "https://www.google.com";
  $homepage = file_get_contents($url);
  $doc = new DOMDocument;
  $doc->loadHTML($homepage);

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($doc);
  exit;
```

**This is example of PHP language. I am looking to see solution in any of the language (Java/.NET).**

**Main question. Is it possible or not?**

So there will be REST API like this & give response in JSON.

```
POST api/getWebsiteData
Params : <Website URL>
```

Sample Response

```
{ 
  "header" : <html goes here>,
  "menu" : <html goes here>,
  "footer" : <html goes here>,
  .....
  ....
}
```

I agree, we will not get 100% solution for this, because some of the website view source is encrypted.

Comment: Please first Try to implement then ask with code snippet.

Comment: Hi @JustIn I have added the sample code. Thanks

Comment: The best way out, use axios with js.

Comment: When you visit a URL, all you get is some client side code having HTML, css and Javascript mostly. So, if you want to pull <header> section from that obviously you can do. But if you want the carousel code then things get different. One is the carousels are mostly powered by JS events, so you will have a hard time tracking JS dependencies of such sections (Carousel), also there are lots of JS carousel libraries are avaiable, so it is not a good idea to check for all the possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, this is not possible.

The longer answer is that you *could* build something that might satisfy your needs, but I can pretty much guarantee that it won't work on the bulk of the web without lots, and lots, and lots of tweaking. And I mean lots. Like so much work that you become Google.

A web page is really composed of two things, HTML and DOM. HTML is what you are going to get from functions like `file_get_contents`, and when the browser interprets them they get converted into DOM. Further, once JavaScript gets involved, it can also modify the DOM as it pleases. Some web pages have a pretty 1-to-1 mapping for initial load with HTML to DOM but others have very minimal HTML and rely on JS to create and manipulate the DOM.

Next, there's CSS and CSSOM, the later of which is what JS has access to, similar to HTML's DOM. In CSS you can say "put the header at the bottom and the footer at the top". How many people do that? Probably zero, that's just a far-fetched example, but there are very many smaller nuanced examples. Some people believe that there should only be one header on a site, while others say that headers hold headings. For instance, you can (and I have seen) headers inside of a footer. (I'm not saying whether I agree or disagree with that, either.) Also, the web is full of HTML with CSS classes like:

```html
<div class="a">...</div>
<div class="b">...</div>
```

Which one of those is the header and which is the footer? Or, which is the sidebar? Is one possibly a menu? Even better, go to the [ReactJS official site](https://reactjs.org/) and inspect their DOM and you'll see code like this:

```html
<div class="css-1vcfx3l"><h3 class="css-1xm4gxl"></h3><div>
```

Do those classes make sense to you?

So if you are going down this path, you are going to have to figure out where you are going to start. Do you just want to parse HTML and ignore JS/CSS/DOM/CSSOM? If so, that's generally called screen scraping (or at least it was when I did it a decade ago).

If you want to get more complex, most browsers can be run in "headless mode" and then interacted with. For instance, there's [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) in headless mode, but I'd really recommend using an abstraction over that such as [Symfony's Panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther) if you are in PHP or [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/) if you are in server-side JS. (I know there are dozens of alternatives, anyone reading this, feel free to throw them in the comments.)

Regardless of simple or complex, you're going to want to write your own rules. A semi-modern site written in the past couple of years has a good chance of having a root or near-root `<HEADER>`, `<MAIN>` and `<FOOTER>` tags. If you find those, your general rules are probably going to be simpler. You stand a good chance of also finding `<ASIDE>` and other semantic HTML5 tags in there, too.

If you don't find those, you might still be able to look at near-root tags for `<div class="header">` and similar. You are going to possibly need to handle alternative versions of `header`, especially across languages (human, not computer, so English, Spanish, etc.).

Using these rules, I think you could generally build something that would parse a good number of sites on the web.

I big word of caution, however, is that home pages tend to be weird and one-offs, because they tend to holds a subset of everything else on the site but no actual content of their own. In that regard, you'll usually still find a header and footer, but inside almost everything feels like a sidebar or similar.

As to carousels? That one is honestly really tough. Carousels are built with JS so if you only look at HTML you might only find a `<UL>` with a bunch of images. Actually, as I write this, I think I would target an `<UL>` with images and assume that they are a carousel. There will definitely be false-positives but it is a pretty common pattern. Not everyone is a `<UL>` fan, however, so they might be just regular `<DIV>`.

I say all this because I have built these in the past, but for very specific sites and for very specific reasons. Writing a general parser that could work everywhere is, as I said at the beginning, a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one and, unless you're google, I doubt it will be possible to make a solution that works on more than a couple websites.

First off lets start out by taking a couple of websites and looking at what they send to the client.

The HTML of a Wikipedia article looks something like this

```
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="History">History</span></h2>
<h3><span class="mw-headline" id="Development">Development</span></h3>
<div class="thumb tright"><div class="thumbinner" style="width:172px;"><a href="/wiki/File:Tim_Berners-Lee_April_2009.jpg" class="image"><img alt="Photograph of Tim Berners-Lee in April 2009" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Tim_Berners-Lee_April_2009.jpg/170px-Tim_Berners-Lee_April_2009.jpg" decoding="async" width="170" height="234" class="thumbimage" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Tim_Berners-Lee_April_2009.jpg/255px-Tim_Berners-Lee_April_2009.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Tim_Berners-Lee_April_2009.jpg/340px-Tim_Berners-Lee_April_2009.jpg 2x" data-file-width="1195" data-file-height="1648" /></a>  <div class="thumbcaption"><div class="magnify"><a href="/wiki/File:Tim_Berners-Lee_April_2009.jpg" class="internal" title="Enlarge"></a></div><a href="/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee" title="Tim Berners-Lee">Tim Berners-Lee</a> in April 2009</div></div></div>
<p>In 1980, physicist <a href="/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee" title="Tim Berners-Lee">Tim Berners-Lee</a>, a contractor at <a href="/wiki/CERN" title="CERN">CERN</a>, proposed and prototyped <a href="/wiki/ENQUIRE" title="ENQUIRE">ENQUIRE</a>, a system for CERN researchers to use and share documents. In 1989, Berners-Lee wrote a memo proposing an <a href="/wiki/Internet" title="Internet">Internet</a>-based <a href="/wiki/Hypertext" title="Hypertext">hypertext</a> system.<sup id="cite_ref-3" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-3">&#91;3&#93;</a></sup> Berners-Lee specified HTML and wrote the browser and server software in late 1990. That year, Berners-Lee and CERN data systems engineer <a href="/wiki/Robert_Cailliau" title="Robert Cailliau">Robert Cailliau</a> collaborated on a joint request for funding, but the project was not formally adopted by CERN. In his personal notes<sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-4">&#91;4&#93;</a></sup> from 1990 he listed<sup id="cite_ref-5" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-5">&#91;5&#93;</a></sup> "some of the many areas in which hypertext is used" and put an encyclopedia first.
```

and this would be easy enough to parse with a php / python / Java program and separate into different parts.

Now lets look at the google support pages. The source is basically 2000 lines of javascript and that's it.
parsing this would be possible, but much harder since you need to actually render the page and execute the javascript before the `<header>`, `<div>` and `<p>` tags appear in the DOM.

I believe it would be possible to create an api thay scans websites like wikipedia or stackoverflow since they generate the HTML on the server side and only require the client to render it and apply css styles to it.

If a website is based upon a technology like react.js you'll see that the entirety of the page is simply javascript and nothing can be processed until that has been executed and rendered.

Would it be possible to reder it and parse it afterwards? Probably yes, but an API that can do this for any given website is so much work that you're probably better of training an AI to read webpages and let it point them out for you.